# Got error in react app You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors, icons

This is my code:

```
import * as Unicons from '@iconscout/react-unicons';
interface Props {
  icon: string;
  color?: string;
  size?: string;
}
export const UniconsCustom = ({ icon, color, size }: Props) => {
  const SelectedIcon = Unicons[icon];
  return <SelectedIcon size={size || '20'} color={color} />;
};
```

When I comment this line `const SelectedIcon = Unicons[icon];` and send an empty fragment on return, it works but doesn't render the icons. Please help.

I'm expecting to render the icon dynamically.